# Regular expression for wrap a group of no-break spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to do that with Jquery + Regular Expression:

For instance:

```
HELLO WORLD&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
HELLO WORLD2&nbsp;&nbsp;HELLO WORLD3&nbsp;
```

final result

```
HELLO WORLD<span class='test'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
HELLO WORLD2<span class='test'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
HELLO WORLD3<span class='test'>&nbsp;</span>
```

I have two doubts:

1.- If the number of no-break spaces is always random, exist a way for wrap this groups with regular expressions?

2.- Only with Jquery or javascript is possible insert in the inital and final position of this group?

Comment: `/(&nbsp;)+/g` is the regex, should be simple from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a modification to @C-link this should do it:

```
var str = 'HELLO WORLD&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;HELLO WORLD2&nbsp;&nbsp;HELLO WORLD3&nbsp;';
var reg = /((?:&nbsp;)+)/g
str.replace(reg,'\<span class\=\"test\" \/\>$1</span>');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aelor, almost works.., I have a strange error, when I put the result inside my Jquery code like here: $("#"+this.id).html(str), in this case the final result in str is: "HELLO WORLD<span class="test"></span><span class="test">&nbsp;</span>HELLO WORLD2" for any reasson when I use the .html() method, create a empty span in the beginning... Do you know why?

Comment: In HTML, elements containing nothing but normal whitespace characters are considered empty. A paragraph that contains just a normal space character will have zero height.

Comment: finally for me works with this trick: document.getElementById("HELLOWORLD_ID").innerHTML = str;

Comment: so what was the way you were trying earlier ? `$("#HELLOWORLD_ID").html(str);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = 'HELLO WORLD&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;HELLO WORLD2&nbsp;&nbsp;HELLO WORLD3';
var reg = /(&nbsp;)+/g
str.replace(reg,'\<span class\=\"test\" \/\>')
```

Comment: C-link Nepal thanks for your contribution, but I need to keep the number of no-break spaces and wrap, with your way works but the no-break spaces are deleted, but is curious.. your have not the problem I had with .hml() jquery method with the last solution.. strange, I don't know what happen ... why change when I use this method for set the html in my text component..